# show number of files not matching certain file name pattern

Tags: find, file-search

I have some non standard and standard filenames like the ones below . I need to get the count of files that are NOT standard..

Standard file names: XYZ*ABC*.txt, XYZ*ABC*.csv, *.msg

Non standard file names: 989875.txt or myname.csv ; this has no bounds and can be anything..

The only good part is I know the standard one and i just need to do a NOT condition to simple find command. How can i do it. Not interested to do a file LOOP etc..

Comment: How about `grep -v XYZABC filenames | grep -v .msg | wc -l`?

Comment: Get number of files, get number of “standard” files. Subtract 2nd from 1st.

Comment: Are they all in the same directory?, are you including all files: regular files, directories etc?

Comment: I need to lok into current directory and NOT should NOT look for any further sub directories.. Just CURRENT directory.. thats it

Answer (score 0):

You could list the files with `ls -1` and perform a `grep -v` to exclude the files that do not meet a condition.  Since you just want a count, you can pipe that through `wc -l` and get the count.  For example

```
ls -1 | grep -v XYZABC | wc -l
```

The only issue is that it also includes the first line which is that of `total`.  You can either subtract 1 from the count, or send the output through `tail +2` before `wc`.

You can handle multiple patterns by using `egrep` as

```
ls -1 | egrep -v "(XYZABC|.msg)" | tail +2 | wc -l
```

Comment: How to get something like this..

Comment: shows the count of all files in the directory but not excluding specific files.. ls -l | egrep -v "(div*gbl*.txt|gbl*.txt)" | wc -l

Comment: That was `ls -1` as in digit `1` and not `ls -l` that you posted.  I fixed that in the answer as well.

Comment: Sorry that was my typo here. it was ls -1(one] but gives me the count of all files and not the ones with my pattern..

Comment: This is my current command ls -1 | egrep -v "(div*wf*.txt|wf*.txt)" | tail +2 | wc -l

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
$ ls
 989875.txt   myname.csv  'some long.msg'   XYZABC.csv   XYZABC.txt
```

Then

```
$ find . ! \( -name 'XYZABC.*' -o -name '*.msg' \)
.
./myname.csv
./989875.txt
```

So for example

```
$ find . -type f ! \( -name 'XYZABC.*' -o -name '*.msg' \) -printf '1' | wc -c
2
```

Comment: I need to count only within current directory and NOT tru any of the sub directories..

Comment: @veekay does your version of `find` have a `maxdepth`? if so, use that i.e. `find -maxdepth 1 -type f ...`

Comment: The printf does not work for me..

Comment: find . ! \( -name 'div*wf*.txt' -o -name 'wf*.txt' \) works for me and lists out required files.. ; but i need to move such files to a different folder. how to do it..  Note: The printf does not work for me ..though..